# Intel compiler does not compile private forward class declaration in another class

Tags: c++, boost, intel

I'm having some problems with Intel compiler 11.1.xxx
Those problems don't appear during compilation with MS CL compiler.
And I don't udnerstand what's wrong with the code (external boost library header)
I end up with multiple errors:

> > ..\boost/log/attributes/attribute_set.hpp(148):
> >     error: declaration is incompatible
> >     with constant "bool fConstV" (declared
> >     at line 147)
> >           template< bool fConstV > friend class iter;
> >                          ^
> >               detected during:
> >                 instantiation of class "boost::log_mt::basic_attribute_set
> >     [with CharT=char]" at line 252 of
> >     "..\boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp"
> >                 instantiation of class "boost::log_mt::sources::basic_logger [with
> >     CharT=char,
> >     FinalT=boost::log_mt::sources::logger,
> >     ThreadingModelT=boost::log_mt::sources::single_thread_model]"
> >     at line 738  of
> >     "..\boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp"
> >                 instantiation of class "boost::log_mt::sources::basic_composite_logger [with CharT=char,
> >     FinalT=boost::log_mt::sources::logger,
> >     FeaturesT=boost::mpl::ve
> >     ctor0]" at line 787 of
> >     "..\boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp"
>
> ..\boost/log/attributes/named_scope.hpp(146):
>   error: declaration is incompatible
>   with constant "bool fConstV" (declared
>   at line 145)
>         template< bool fConstV > friend class iter;
>                        ^
>             detected during:
>               instantiation of class "boost::log_mt::attributes::basic_named_scope_list
>   [with CharT=char]" at line 364
>               instantiation of class "boost::log_mt::attributes::basic_named_scope
>   [with CharT=char]" at line 94 of
>   "..\boost/log/formatters/named_scope.hpp"
>               instantiation of class "boost::log_mt::formatters::fmt_named_scope
>   [with CharT=char]" at line 270 of
>   "..\boost/log/formatters/named_scope.hpp"

attributeset.hpp

```
    template< typename CharT >
    class basic_attribute_set
    {
        /* ... */
        template< bool fConstV > class iter;
        template< bool fConstV > friend class iter;
        template< bool fConstV >

       class iter
       {
            friend class iter< !fConstV >;
            friend class basic_attribute_set< CharT >;
            /* ... */
            /* ... */
       }
    }
```

basiclogger.hpp

```
   class logger : public basic_composite_logger< char, logger, single_thread_model, mpl::vector0< > >
   {
       BOOST_LOG_FORWARD_LOGGER_CONSTRUCTORS(logger)
   };
```

Any hints welcome.

Comment: I've removed 147 & 148 then code compiled properely,
but I haven't linked it yet.
I'll update this message if the binary will work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe at line 148 you want `template <bool fConstV> friend class iter<fConstV>;`?  Though, as `iter` is declared as a nested class, I don't think you need the friend declaration;

Comment: template <bool fConstV> friend class iter<fConstV>;
This doesn't work, for now only thing which is working is removing booth forward declarations.